# global formfield_overriding in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have custom textfield widget and many form in my project. To use this custom widget i need to to write:

```
formfield_overrides = {
    TextField: {'widget': CustomTextFieldWidget},
}
```

in every `admin.ModelAdmin` form, and that's just ugly.

Is there a way to write it just once and use custom widget across all forms in project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no hook to override formfield widgets across an entire project.

You could make all of your model admin classes inherit from a subclass of `admin.ModelAdmin`, then you only have to set `formfield_overrides` once.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    This is the parent class that all model 
    admins in the project inherit from
    """
    formfield_overrides = {
        TextField: {'widget': CustomTextFieldWidget},
    }

class AppleAdmin(MyModelAdmin):
    ...

class BananaAdmin(MyModelAdmin):
    ...

#etc
```